# NodeJS - How to get the last opened date attribute of a file?

Tags: node.js

I was using `fs` library to get the details of a file.

The return is something like this:

```
{
  dev: 16777221,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 28314867,
  size: 2000,
  blocks: 8,
  atimeMs: 1599139438255.0735,
  mtimeMs: 1599139421301.3347,
  ctimeMs: 1599139421301.3347,
  birthtimeMs: 1599002337452.0671,
  atime: 2020-09-03T13:23:58.255Z,
  mtime: 2020-09-03T13:23:41.301Z,
  ctime: 2020-09-03T13:23:41.301Z,
  birthtime: 2020-09-01T23:18:57.452Z
}
```

I am hoping to get the last opened date attribute of a file. The `atime` field doesn't seem to get updated when opening the file.

`ctime` is updated, but it says [here](https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/fs-stats-structure.html) that `ctime` will be updated even by just updating the permissions of the file.

---

TLDR:
Is it possible to get the last opened field of a file similar to Mac's finder? (see image)

[image: Screenshot of file info]

Comment: depends if you mount with noatime option then atime is kinda turned off, also note those times are not by file but by node, multiple hardlinks share same, at least in linux

Comment: hi @Estradiaz, can the mounting be done through nodeJs code? Is it some kind of configuration we can add when reading the file through `fs.stat`?

Comment: i think its not implememted in fs - but for linux its like this: https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Noatime, its a feature you should not depend on as its favoured to be turned of to reduce writes